# Check if a thread exists by it handle

Tags: delphi, multithreading

When I create a thread I save it handle in a list.
After a time I want to check which of them still exists.
I'm not looking for other kind of implementation, I want to know if is there some how to get a thread by it handle ?

Comment: A thread exists until you join it. Do you want to check which ones are still running?

Comment: @Marcelo, joining has nothing to do with it. A thread exists as long as there are still handles open to it. And even if they're all closed, the thread will still exist if it hasn't terminated yet.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I confused POSIX and Win32.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer tks srs.

GetExitCodeThread

For more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683190(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you're just interested in which ones are still running, this should work:

```
if WaitForSingleObject(ThreadHandle, 0) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
  // Thread is still running
```

Comment: This way I'll wait of thread finalization, it's not the case, tks anyway.

Comment: The second argument to WaitForSingleObject is a timeout.  By passing 0 in it will just test the wait state and immediately return.